# Increment Autofill Range by Variable Number

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

A requirement for a work project is to sum hourly values together by day for a certain number of categories.  These values are stored in a spreadsheet in one long column; to get the values, I sum every 24 rows into a new day.  This can be accomplished by looping through the spreadsheet and increasing the values for each loop by 24.

For example:

```
first = 1
second = 24
i = 0
While Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").offset(i, 0) <> ""
    Worksheets("Data").Range("C1").offset(i, 0).Formula = "=SUM(B" & first & ":B" & second & ")")
    first = first + 24
    second = second + 24
Wend
```

Where column A is the category and column B is the hourly data. Column B will be the length of column A * 24.

This produces results like...

```
=SUM(B1:B24)
=SUM(B25:B48)
=SUM(B49:B72)
```

.. and so on.

This works well, but is very slow.  What I would like to do is use AutoFill for the entire range, but I'm not sure how to write it in such a way that it will increment the values by 25 each time.  So far I have only been able to get it to increment by one for each value, where

```
=SUM(B1:B24)
```

becomes

```
=SUM(B2:B25)
```

Is there a way to use AutoFill on a range where it will increment by a variable number -- in this case, 24?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that your actual code?  Where are you incrementing i ?

Comment: Isn't it possible at all to use Excel Subtotals? It would do the trick (as long as you have a column with the day) pretty easily.

Comment: @Tim: No, it's sample code demonstrating the idea.  I see now I should have reviewed it further.  In the loop, i would be incremented by one.

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso: I'll try Subtotals; I'm not at work right now but I'll give it a shot tomorrow morning.  Thanks.

Comment: Well @PaulR, as I said... there are plenty of ways of doing the same thing, maybe with Subtotals, maybe as I mentioned below... just chose the one that best fits your needs :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be plenty of ways to do it, both using or not VBA.

I present you a solution using only Excel, but can be migrated to VBA to avoid other column's usage (I believe there must be a way to do it without using support columns, someone else here in the community might remember how, eventually).

Well, the trick here is use the `INDIRECT` formula.

I'll assume you're applying the sum formula into column C.

In columns D and E, you will store the row indexes. Then, we'll have:

```
|D      |E      |
|-------|-------|
|1      |24     |
|=D1+24 |=E1+24 |
|=D2+24 |=E2+24 |
```

Now, in column C, instead of using Sum with direct values, use:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B"&D1):INDIRECT("B"&E1))
=SUM(INDIRECT("B"&D2):INDIRECT("B"&E2))
=SUM(INDIRECT("B"&D3):INDIRECT("B"&E3))
```

This code can be dragged down as much as you want, as long as you drag the columns C, D and E together.

Again, it could also be done in a fancier way using VBA (and maybe in a smarter way using only Excel, hehe) but that's the way that came up to my mind. Anyway, most of the questions I've seen here about simple VBA implementations were for personal usage, so use other columns wouldn't be a problem.

In case you prefer (or need) to use VBA, draft your code and we'll be helping you out.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tiago, that's not a half bad idea.  I'll give it a shot first thing tomorrow morning and let you know.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

If your only complaint with your current approach is its speed, then you can probably make it significantly faster by suspending calculation while you insert the formula:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'do your thing
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Tim, thanks for the suggestion.   I have a method that kicks off every process in my spreadssheet, and I have these lines at the beginning and end of this "main" method.